# PHP: Inserting Multiple array into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, mysqli

I am testing multiple array insertion into my table, I have try all what I could but I am not getting.Here is my code:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    //ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
                     $message = array();    

                    $id =1;
                    $SocialHandle = "Facebook,Twitter,LinkIn";
                    $SociaUrl ="Url1,Url2,Url3";

                    $strSocialHandle = explode(',', $SocialHandle); 
                    $strSociaUrl = explode(',', $SociaUrl); 
                    print_r($strSocialHandle);
                    print_r($strSociaUrl);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `social_table`(`id`, `social_handle`, `handle_url`) VALUES";
                    foreach($strSocialHandle as $SocialNameValue){                                      
                    $sql .= "({$id}, '{$SocialNameValue}','{$strSociaUrl}'),";              
                    }
                    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
                    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

                    if (!$result){
                            $message = array('Message' => 'insert fail or record exist');
                            echo json_encode($message);         
                    }else{             
                            $message = array('Message' => 'new record inserted');
                            echo json_encode($message);   
                    }
?>
```

Here is my goal achievement:

> ID         social handle      
>      handle url 
>  1           Facebook
>             url1 
>  1        
>     Twitter              url2 
>  1
>             LinkIn        
>        url3

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: yeah: Error Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: if `ID` is a primary key - it should be unique, (not repeating values)

Comment: is a sub table under my database so the table does not have Unique ID

Comment: i think where my problem is i need to loop through the both array and implode them which i have no idea how that can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop for it as

```
$id =1;
$SocialHandle = "Facebook,Twitter,LinkIn";
$SocialHandle = explode(",", $SocialHandle);
$SociaUrl = "Url1,Url2,Url3";
$SociaUrl = explode(",", $SociaUrl);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `social_table`(`id`, `social_handle`, `handle_url`) VALUES";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($SocialHandle); $i++) {
    $sql .= "({$id}, '$SocialHandle[$i]','$SociaUrl[$i]'),";
}


$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
echo $sql;
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

**OUTPUT**

> INSERT INTO `social_table`(`id`, `social_handle`, `handle_url`)
>   VALUES(1, 'Facebook','Url1'),(1, 'Twitter','Url2'),(1,
>   'LinkIn','Url3')

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/nQsGY)

**UPDATED**

Better use prepare and bind statement to prevent form sql injection as

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($SocialHandle); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `social_table`(`id`, `social_handle`, `handle_url`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $id, $SocialHandle[$i], $SociaUrl[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: who down vote this answer is actually what am looking for

Comment: The "updated" version has multiple inserts; that is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

You're only looping over `$strSocialHandle` - the `$strSociaUrl` array isn't affected by the loop, so will still be an array rather than an individual value. You can store the two lists in a single key-value array, and use one loop to iterate over both:

```
<?php
$id = 1;

$social = [
    'Facebook' => 'Url1',
    'Twitter'  => 'Url2',
    'LinkIn'   => 'Url3',
];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `social_table`(`id`, `social_handle`, `handle_url`) VALUES";

foreach($social as $handle => $url) {
    $sql .= "({$id}, '{$handle}','{$url}'),";
}

echo rtrim($sql, ',');
```

Comment: What if a social handle is like BoobyTables';drop table users; --? Just curious.

Comment: Is Booby Tables related to Bobby Tables?

Comment: It's up to you to decide.